# Complete iPhone backup without iTunes?

Tags: backup, iphone, itunes

Okay so I'm having major issues installing/running iTunes through Wine, but I'm in major need to create (and be able to restore from) a full, complete backup for my iPhone since I'm doing a ton of tweaking to it. I don't really know what I'm doing, so there's a 110% chance I'm gonna screw it up, but hey, no one ever learned anything about technology without crashing it a good 100 times right? =P

Answer (score 3):

It's more recommend to create a VM and install iTunes on it, so that you can perform a full/complete backup.

To create a VM, there is a official doc via wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox.

Another discussion: [How to install Windows 7 inside Virtualbox of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49086/how-to-install-windows-7-inside-virtualbox-of-ubuntu)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I dont have a copy of windows, or any other non-linux-based os with me, and I can't download it either since I'm using mobile broadband data.

Is there anything else I could do? I got iTunes 10 runnung under PlayOnLinux, but it doesnt find or even react to any iDevice being plugged in.

Answer (score 3):

It does appear that there is a backup utility for idevices although I admit I haven't tested it out yet.  I found this though:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/idevicebackup.1.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi! I had no luck using this.  it may be still on development or beta testing, as user or su I had System Errors...

Comment: Confirmed not working with iphone 5, ios 10, ubuntu 17.10 beta2. `Device is not ready yet. Going to try again in 2 seconds...` Maybe in time for iphone XIV?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I just had a similar problem. @Andreas: you have to unlock the device (enter the PIN); you might also try to pair it first via `idevicepair pair`.