# Booting windows from inside ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-8

My laptop has pre-installed Windows 8. I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside it.

Now I want only one boot option that is - Ubuntu. I want to be able to boot Windows 8 only from inside Ubuntu(through Terminal, most preferably).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thanks all, but I already knew about the Virtual OS. I just wanted to make sure if it is possible. Now I know it's not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run windows inside the Ubuntu only through the Virtual Machine.
Refer the following link : [Install Windows 7 inside Virtualbox of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49086/how-to-install-windows-7-inside-virtualbox-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way booting another OS through terminal. Except, you mean something like virtual OS.

If so, you can download virtualbox through apt-get and then setting up the environment.

Or, I found a way to boot already installed one, but this tutorial only tested in Windows XP. I already tried it and it works (Win XP). [Here](http://mesbalivernes.blogspot.com/2008/01/virtual-box-booting-from-existing.html), take a look.

1. Maybe, you can change the command as follow.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox

   sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./Win8.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda
   sudo apt-get install mbr
   sudo install-mbr --force myBootRecord.mbr
   sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ./Win8-ready.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1 -mbr ./myBootRecord.mbr -relative
   ```
2. Then, start your virtualbox

   ```
   $ gksudo virtualbox
   ```
3. Make new virtual OS.
4. Set Type:MsWindows; Version:Win8; blabla then Next.
5. Next again.
6. On 'HardDrive' part, select 'Use an Existing...', click browse icon.
7. Choose Win8-ready.vmdk on file browser.
8. Then, create.

   Notice, all commands use *super user* authority.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this question

[How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu)

Basically you will be using your grub entries as a reference to reboot to Windows from inside Ubuntu. But this would still require to have a grub entry for Windows. Not sure if you can completely remove it.