# Firefox and chrome is not working on a website

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, webapps, websites

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. I found a website where I can learn German language, but unfortunately the page is not working. I tried Firefox and Chrome both of them, I disabled addblock, but still it is not woking. I dont know what is the problem. Can any one give me an idea what can I do to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

**The website link is http://lernen.goethe.de/spiele/lerndeutsch/web.html**

Answer (score 2):

Some of the opening javascript from the page:

```
var unityObjectUrl = "http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js";
```

It needs the [Unity Web Player](https://unity3d.com/webplayer) to work but Unity hasn't released a version for Linux (yet). I'm not happy with any of these solutions but there are a few options...

- [Use pipelight to run the plugin under Wine](https://askubuntu.com/a/498915/449). If this works, it's probably going to be the least jarring for you but I would be very cautious about running it on any website. Wine could be a weak link in the secuiryt of your browser.
- [Use a virtual machine with Windows](https://askubuntu.com/q/49086/449).
- Ask the website creator to create a HTML version.
- Ask the website creator to release a standalone version for Linux (Unity can do *that*).
- Find another cross-platform resource.